# How to install the browser Pale Moon under Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, palemoon

How do I install the web browser 'Pale Moon' under Bionic Beaver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser Pale Moon as yet does not exist in the Bionic Beaver repositories but there is a *dependable* PPA available that has the nod of approval of the Pale Moon developers.

Add the PPA and install Pale Moon with the following *one liner*:

```
echo "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:\
/stevenpusser/x$(lsb_release -sir | paste -sd_)/ /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:stevenpusser.list && \
wget -nv \
https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:stevenpusser/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key \
-O Release.key && \
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key && \
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install palemoon
```

Then take this new kid on the block (comparatively!) for a test run:

[image]

**Notes:**

- [Blessing for the PPA from the Developers](https://forum.palemoon.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=105790#p105790) There was a period of instability with the Pale Moon packages from this PPA but resolved as of version 27.1
- [Download Pale Moon for Linux Installer](http://linux.palemoon.org/download/installer/) A linux 'installer' is available as well, untested by me.
- [Download Pale Moon for Linux release binaries](http://linux.palemoon.org/download/mainline/) Another choice is to download pre-compiled binaries and load these into your `$PATH`, untested by me.